# Disable or change Firefox's element/image highlight color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get rid of the faded blue highlight color for certain elements (in particular, images).  Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Qqzq/26/) for examplary purposes. Notice that when you highlight the text, it's appropriately yellow, as per the CSS. But when you drag-select to encompass the kittens, and/or you simply press CTRL+A to highlight the entire body, you get the faded blue selection color around the images.

Chrome lets you disable this entirely and/or change it. Is there really no Mozilla equivalent? Because evidently `::-moz-selection` is not the answer:

```
div ::-moz-selection {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

This only works for the text. What about a method using JavaScript? Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Dublicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826782/css-rule-to-disable-text-selection-highlighting)

Comment: No it isn't? I'm not talking about text-selection. Text-selection was shown to be altered in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can change the color of the highlight on the image but you can get rid of the highlight completely by doing this:

```
div {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Qqzq/33/

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Comment: I've tried applying that to 'html' in my CSS, with no success. Is that improper usage for some reason? Should I not be able to set it for the entire document on 'html' or 'body'?